# Excel adding rows based on if they are a number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to add rows in a column based on whether or not they are a number. 
Some rows are numbers and some are not.

I have something like the following. But it's not right:

```
=SUMIF(ISNUMBER(C1051:C1055)="TRUE",C1051:C1055)
```

I'm not sure - how to do this calculation. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=COUNTIF(C1051:C1055,">0")

This works if you have numbers that are greater than zero. However I like to always use Countifs in case I ever want to add another condition later. in which case I would use =COUNTIFS(C1051:C1055,">0").

Comment: Thanks. I just discovered that this works : =SUMIF(C2:C1055,">0",C2:C1055)